# How do i get vite-plugin-fonts to work? Nothing happens

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello I wanted to import a custom font using vite and found this plugin, vite-plugin-fonts, and set it up like so:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import * as path from "path";
import ViteFonts from "vite-plugin-fonts";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    ViteFonts({
      // Custom fonts.
      custom: {
        families: [
          {
            name: "Gilroy-Light",
            local: "Gilroy-Light",
            src: "./fonts/Gilroy-Light.otf",
          },
        ],
        display: "auto",
        preload: true,
      },
    }),
  ],

});
```

and in my css

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Gilroy-Light", sans-serif;
}
```

but it does not work. what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to import and register the fonts via `@font-face` for example. This plugin will just make sure your font is preloaded on the page adding
`<link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/otf" href="/assets/yourfont.otf" crossorigin>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).